# ModalPopupExtender including a DropDownList after the SelectedIndexChanged popup closing itself?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, modalpopupextender, selectedindexchanged

I have a ModalPopupExtender on one my pages which I am using to render a form to the user, the form contains several fields including a DropDownList with its AutoPostBack property set to true. When the user changes the selected item in the DropDownList POSTBACK occurs and then the modal popup is automatically closed. If I reopen the popup at this point the correct partial updates have been applied, but I do not want the popup to close itself. Because of how the page is constructed (the content of the modal popup is a user control) I can't simply tell the page to redisplay the popup after the SelectedIndexChanged event of the DropDownList. Is there any way to prevent the popup from closing itself?

Answer (score -1):

```
 ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

Use this in the drop down list selected index changed event in code behind